# python convert voice to text

Tags: python, google-speech-api

how to convert voice to text using `google.cloud.speech` python. I want to convert `audio.raw` file data to `text` using SpeechClient. In client.py file read each `332 characters` of audio data and send it via socket. In server.py receive 332 character from socket and convert it to text using SpeechClient.

here is my sample code

client.py

```
# coding:utf-8
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
from contextlib import closing
import socket
import time
import sys
import os
import struct
import logging

def send():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    with closing(sock):
        with open('audio.raw', 'rb') as f:
            packets = iter(lambda: f.read(332), b'')
            for packet in packets:
                try:
                    sock.sendto(packet, ('192.168.10.64', 12345))
                    time.sleep(0.02)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('==================Testing=======================')
    send()
    print('===============Finished Test===============')
```

server.py

```
# coding:utf-8
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
from contextlib import closing
import socket
import time
import sys
import os
import struct
import logging

def socket_open():
    print('=========================================')

    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')
    streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
        config=config)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    with closing(sock):
        sock.bind(('192.168.10.64', 12345))
        print('socket ok')

        first_packet = None
        while True:
            try:
                first_packet = sock.recv(332)
                stream = [first_packet]
                requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=chunk)
                            for chunk in stream)
                responses = client.streaming_recognize(
                    streaming_config, requests)
                for response in responses:
                    for result in response.results:
                        print('Finished: {}'.format(result.is_final))
                        print('Stability: {}'.format(result.stability))
                        alternatives = result.alternatives
                        for alternative in alternatives:
                            print('Confidence: {}'.format(
                                alternative.confidence))
                            print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(
                                alternative.transcript))
                sock.settimeout(300)
            except socket.timeout:
                print('socket timeout error')
                break
            except socket.error:
                print('socket error occured')
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('==================Open Socket=======================')
    socket_open()
    print('===============Finished Socket===============')
```

I got output responses is empty.